# SharePoint Mobile not working for Photos

Tags: sharepoint-online, mobile

I have an Asset Library with many photos.  When I use the SharePoint mobile app provided by Microsoft, nothing renders properly.  When I go to the page that contains the Library it looks like this:

[image]

This is quite useless.  The thumbnail doesn't render and none of my metadata is appearing.

When I enter the library itself this is what appears:

[image]

When I go to Site Contents -> Photo Library it renders correctly, like so

[image]

Has anyone else had issues with the SharePoint Online Mobile app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the copy link button for each image, the shareable link, and used that as the image hyperlink rather than copying the URL from OneDrive to Sharepoint list like this:  /Documents//.jpg

If the problem persists, try using a different mobile browser.